# "/" maps to /WEB-INF/pages/ -- why?

Tags: spring

For some reason /WEB-INF/pages seems to have become a root folder. Any request to / goes to /pages/. For instance, the following request goes to /pages/index.jsp.

That's a bit of a problem because I've also got a /WEB-INF/secure folder, which I don't get how to reach.

Why is this...?

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
    return "index";
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/springmvc-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Edit as per request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc.service"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>

    <!--
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we see your Spring servlet bean config as well?

Probably you have an `InternalResourceViewResolver` pointing at `/WEB-INF/pages/`.

For example, look for something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
    p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Comment: I *did* have that actually, but I tried commenting out and even deleting that part, with no success.

Comment: Try reinstating the config, but change the name of the directory to /WEB-INF/something_else/, just to determine whether this is the mechanism. If it works, then you may have a cached copy of the file somewhere, so do a clean build.

Comment: I changed the value to "value="/WEB-INF/something/", but it's still loading /pages, so it seems you're right. I tried redeploying, restarting the server and doing an invalidate cashes / restart in IntelliJ and none of them helped though. So how on earth do I get rid of the cached version...?

Comment: With Tomcat you can delete the Tomcat work directory. I'm not sure which container you're using or how IntelliJ invokes it. You might create that as a separate question.

Comment: Incidentally, the test you just performed doesn't really establish that it's a cached version. I would have preferred to see a result where /WEB-INF/something/ *did* change the mapping. Still I suspect that a cached version of the config might be sitting around. You could try building directly on the command line with Maven or Gradle to see.

Comment: Hmm, right, , but I don't have any mention *anywhere* of /pages/ in my code (did a search), so I'll work under the assumption of it being a cached version for now.